# How to represent Array of integers in handlebar.js

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a json object "FoundAt" : [1, 3]
How do I represent the values in the array using handlebar.js?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to iterating the array you can do so using `{{each}}` block, with reference to the above defined array use the following:

```
 {{#each jsonObjectName.FoundAt}}
  {{this}}
 {{/each}}
```

OR

```
 {{#each number in jsonObjectName.FoundAt}}
  {{number}}
 {{/each}}
```

Look for Simple Iterators in the official [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html)